# Powershell; Click on a specific link out of a number of similar links

Tags: powershell

Every month I have to dl a lot of bills from a lot of different accounts at the same provider. I already get my script to log in to these accounts and navigate to the correct site.
The problem is, there are a lot of bills to dl at that site and I only want to dl the most recent. Usually the first link on the site, formatted like this:

```
<div class="dataTable-cell dataTable-cell--w20">
                <div class="btn btn--secondary">
                    <a href="/myaccount/bills/bill_download/stringofcharacters" onclick="track('bill_download',{'prop3':'Button:bills','events92':1});">Download</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I just can't get my script to click the link. Any ideas? I've already tried multiple ways to get the link, but nothing worked (-eq, -match, -contains etc.)
This is what I have so far:

```
$username = "username" 
$password = "password" 
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("https://provider.domain/login") 
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100} 
$ie.document.getElementById("IDToken1").value= "$username" 
$ie.document.getElementById("IDToken2").value = "$password" 
$loginBtn = $ie.Document.getElementById("Login.Submit")
$loginBtn.click();
start-sleep 5
$ie.navigate("https://provider.domain/myaccount/bills/") 
start-sleep 5
```

Comment: Get-Help Invoke-WebRequest -Full . also you might need a tool like fiddler: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler . in any case youd better post what you have so far

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to get "a" elements, you can do it like this:

```
$aElements = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
```

There are, for sure, many of them. So you have to select right one among them. From you example I can see that it has textContent "Download", so use this code:

```
$downloadLink = ($aElements | where {$_.textContent -like "Download"})
```

However, if there are few links with "Download" text on them and you need only first, use the following:

```
$downloadLinks = ($aElements | where {$_.textContent -like "Download"})
$downloadLink = $downloadLinks | Select-Object -First 1
```

Finally, you can do

```
$downloadLink.click()
```